# What should I say after allowing someone asking for going forward from behind me?

Tags: politeness, responses

I am in problem to respond a person after let her pass from behind me when he asks for a side by saying "excuse me,side please"?

Comment: A common phrase is: *go ahead.*

Comment: As Sander has said, or you can say in a friendly way, "After you."

Comment: I would say "Sorry I am in your way." even if I am not it is polite.

Comment: "No problem." (US) Where is this occurring? If someone did say, "excuse me, side please," that doesn't sound American or British to me.

Answer (score 3):

"Go ahead", which was suggested in the comments, is a fine response.

Usually, I would just say "Oops, sorry" to indicate that I was unaware that I blocking someone's way.

Comment: Thanks all for your cordial cooperation. In addition may i say "follow you"?

Comment: "Follow you" sounds like you're expecting to be led somewhere, or you're stalking someone. Instead, say "After you" to mean that you want the other person to pass first.